# OpenMP Handmade reduction directive

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm working on factorial function. I have to write its parallel version using OpenMP.

```
double sequentialFactorial(const int N) {
    double result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is well known that this algorithm can be efficiently parallelized using reduction tecnique.

I'm aware of the existence of `reduction` clause ([standard](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) §§ 2.15.3.6).

```
double parallelAutomaticFactorial(const int N) {
    double result = 1;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(*:result)
    for (int i=1; i <= N; i++) 
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

However, I want to try to implement reduction tecnique "handmade".

```
double parallelHandmadeFactorial(const int N) {

    // maximum number of threads
    const int N_THREADS = omp_get_max_threads();

    // table of partial results
    double* partial = new double[N_THREADS];
    for(int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
        partial[i] = 1;
    }

    // reduction tecnique
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        int thread_index = omp_get_thread_num();
        partial[thread_index] *= i;
    }

    // fold results
    double result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
        result *= partial[i];
    }

    delete partial;

    return result;
}
```

I expect the performance of the last two snippet to be very similar, and better than the first one. However, the average performance is:

```
Sequential Factorial          3500 ms
Parallel Handmade Factorial   6100 ms
Parallel Automatic Factorial   600 ms
```

Am I missing something?

---

Thanks to @Gilles and @P.W, this code works as expected

```
double parallelNoWaitFactorial(const int N) {

    double result = 1;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        double my_local_result = 1;

        // removing nowait does not change the performance
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            my_local_result *= i;

        #pragma omp atomic
        result *= my_local_result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're in the textbook case of false sharing. Just get rid of the `partial` array and use a local variable that you reduce with a `critical` directive and that should be good.

Comment: Also calling `omp_get_thread_num` within the loop can't be too good either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If array elements happen to share a cache line, this leads to [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) which further leads to performance degradation.

To avoid this:

- Use a private variable `double partial` instead of the `double` array
  `partial`.
- Use the `partial` result of each thread to compute the final `result` in a critical region
- This final `result` should a variable that is not private to the parallel region.

The critical region will look like this:

```
#pragma omp critical
    result *= partial;
```

Comment: Note that `omp atomic` is preferred over `omp critical` when possible.